# how to make a toast for spinner database in android

Tags: android, database, spinner, toast

i populate a spinner from database.... now i need to make a toast for spinner..... how to do that

### My code :

```
Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

AdapterCountries = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
AdapterCountries.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spin.setAdapter(AdapterCountries);



Cursor cursor = db.getAllTitles1();
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
results=cursor.getString(2);
AdapterCountries.add(results);
 }
db.close();`
```

anyone can help me pls.....

Thanks

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking for. Do you want to display a spinner inside a toast? Do you want to display a toast every time you make a selection in a spinner?

Comment: @rogerkk i want to make a toast for selection item in the spinner... like "you have select the item:Item1"... thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by setting a `OnItemSelectedListener` on your spinner. Beneath is an example:

```
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            String country = (String)AdapterCountries.get(postion);
            Toast.makeText(<YourActivityNameHere>.this, "You selected " + country, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html
Set listener for your spinner and display toast in onItemSelected.